# How to establish a stable Wifi connection on Android on an Apple Airport based network with multiple airports

Tags: android, networking, wifi, connectivity

I'm building an app to let the user upload large files when connected to wifi. The only problem is that when connected to a multiple airport extended wifi network, the phone keeps switching between MAC addresses on the SAME SSID.  I end up with a series of timeouts and disconnects and reconnects.

Can anyone shed some light on my issue here?  Is it a phone setup issue with the network, is it the network setup or perhaps the way apple airport network work with android wifi? Maybe it's a firmware incompatibility? I just can't seem to hold onto a connection in a consistent manner to finish my upload.

Using Gingerbread 2.3.4 and 2.3.3

Here is the log from one session

```
06-15 11:04:07.366 E/upload  (20974): ConnectTimeoutException error
06-15 11:06:03.863 E/upload  (20974): ConnectTimeoutException error
06-15 11:12:51.414 E/upload  (20974): ConnectTimeoutException error
06-15 11:21:11.972 E/upload  (20974): ConnectTimeoutException error
06-15 11:21:29.027 E/upload  (20974): ConnectTimeoutException error

06-15 11:03:56.624 V/WifiStateTracker(  106): New network state is CONNECTED
06-15 11:04:06.737 V/WifiStateTracker(  106): New network state is DISCONNECTED
06-15 11:04:07.312 V/WifiStateTracker(  106): New network state is CONNECTED
06-15 11:06:04.874 V/WifiStateTracker(  106): New network state is DISCONNECTED
06-15 11:12:17.863 V/WifiStateTracker(  106): New network state is CONNECTED
06-15 11:12:50.699 V/WifiStateTracker(  106): New network state is DISCONNECTED
06-15 11:12:50.718 V/WifiStateTracker(  106): New network state is DISCONNECTED
06-15 11:12:51.374 V/WifiStateTracker(  106): New network state is CONNECTED
06-15 11:21:11.269 V/WifiStateTracker(  106): New network state is DISCONNECTED
06-15 11:21:11.921 V/WifiStateTracker(  106): New network state is CONNECTED
```

Comment: Sounds like a serious issue with your Airport OR a strange compatibility issue with 2.3. Have you tested on a different network?

Comment: Yeah, I went to the Apple store to see if it was the same issue and it was.  Since I figure the Apple store has a multiple airport network.  Uploading to YouTube works fine, but I can't get it working with my app.

Comment: Did your log output look the same on their network?